# Repeat CSS settings for every image in loop (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, loops, slider

I have this HTML for image slider:

```
<div>
    <ul id="imageContainer">
        <li><img src="image-1.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-2.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-3.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-4.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-5.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-6.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-7.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-8.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="image-9.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am using map method to apply CSS settings to all images:

```
var imageContainer = $('#imageContainer'),
states = [
    { zIndex: 1, width: 120, height: 347, top: 0, left: 170, opacity: 0 },
    { zIndex: 2, width: 130, height: 390, top: 0, left: 0, opacity: 1 },
    { zIndex: 3, width: 160, height: 475, top: 0, left: 147, opacity: 1 },
    { zIndex: 4, width: 220, height: 638, top: 0, left: 322, opacity: 1 },
    { zIndex: 3, width: 160, height: 475, top: 0, left: 555, opacity: 1 },
    { zIndex: 2, width: 130, height: 390, top: 0, left: 730, opacity: 1 },
    { zIndex: 1, width: 120, height: 347, top: 0, left: 570, opacity: 0 },
];

imageContainer.map(function(index, element) {
    imageContainer.find('li:last').prependTo(imageContainer);
    var state = states[index];
    $(element).animate(state);
});
```

This works if I am using 7 images (I have 7 states in object), but I am using 9 images (CSS settings are applied only to first 7 images, the last 2 are undefined). How can I use these CSS settings if I have more than 7 images?

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marek8623/xpvt214o/990609/). I do not see 8th and 9th image in the slider.

Comment: What do you want to do, start back at beginning of array again?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I want to repeat these settings for every image.

Comment: @charlietfl I have included fiddle example of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't add more state in your `states` object but, you can check before your function if the `li` count is more than `states` object.

This example below work. I used **modulo** for add more value in `states` object. I add a litle short code inside your `$lis.each` function. Please see

```js
$(function () {
 $('.slide').customSlide();
});

(function($) {
    var slide = function(ele, options) {
        var $ele = $(ele);
        var setting = {
            speed: 1000,
            interval: 2000,
        };
  var cssPercentFromTop = 50 + '%';
  var states = [
      { zIndex: 1, width: 120, height: 347, top: cssPercentFromTop, left: 170, opacity: 0 },
      { zIndex: 2, width: 130, height: 390, top: cssPercentFromTop, left: 0, opacity: 1 },
      { zIndex: 3, width: 160, height: 475, top: cssPercentFromTop, left: 147, opacity: 1 },
      { zIndex: 4, width: 220, height: 638, top: cssPercentFromTop, left: 322, opacity: 1 },
      { zIndex: 3, width: 160, height: 475, top: cssPercentFromTop, left: 555, opacity: 1 },
      { zIndex: 2, width: 130, height: 390, top: cssPercentFromTop, left: 730, opacity: 1 },
      { zIndex: 1, width: 120, height: 347, top: cssPercentFromTop, left: 570, opacity: 0 },
  ];
        
  $.extend(true, setting, options);

        var $lis = $ele.find('li');
        var timer = null;

        $ele.find('.custom-slider-next').on('click', function() {
            next();
        });
        
  $ele.find('.custom-slider-prev').on('click', function() {
            states.push(states.shift());
            move();
        });
        
  $ele.on('mouseenter', function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }).on('mouseleave', function() {
            //autoPlay();
        });

        move();
        //autoPlay();

        function move() {

         var imageContainer = $('.custom-slider ul');
         imageContainer.find('li:last').prependTo(imageContainer);
      
      $lis.each(function(index, element) {
    ///// NEW CODE BY P.Frank /////
        if(index >= states.length){
         var tap = index % states.length;
          states.push(states[tap])
        }
        ///// NEW CODE BY P.Frank /////
        
    var state = states[index];

    $(element).animate(state, setting.speed);
    $(element).css('transform', 'translate(0, -50%)');
   });

        }

        function next() {
            states.unshift(states.pop());
            move();
        }

        function autoPlay() {
            timer = setInterval(next, setting.interval);
        }
    }
    
 $.fn.customSlide = function(options) {
        $(this).each(function(index, ele) {
            slide(ele, options);
        });
        return this;
    }
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.custom-slider {
 position: relative;
 width: 860px;
 height: 375px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.custom-slider .custom-slider-next,
.custom-slider .custom-slider-prev {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -96px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-slider .custom-slider-prev {
 left: -200px;
}

.custom-slider .custom-slider-next {
 right: -200px;
}

.custom-slider ul {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 860px;
 height: 630px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

.custom-slider ul li {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
 left: 377px;
 top: 146px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.custom-slider ul li img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide custom-slider">
  <div class="custom-slider-prev">
    <img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/hardware/keyboard_arrow_left_black_192x192.png" alt="">
 </div>
  <div class="custom-slider-next">
    <img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/hardware/keyboard_arrow_right_black_192x192.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=1" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=2" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=3" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=4" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=5" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=6" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=7" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=8" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=9" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I cannot use more states in my states object because I do not know how many images will be added into the slider by the client. But thank you very much for your help. You are great! :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you wan't to loop thru your states array I think you can do something like this:

```
imageContainer.map(function(index, element) {
    imageContainer.find('li:last').prependTo(imageContainer);
    var state = states[index % states.length];
    $(element).animate(state);
});
```

index % states.length returns the remainder from dividing the index by the length of the state array.

Comment: Your solution adds settings to every image, but when I keep sliding images they are not sliding in order.

Comment: I have included fiddle example of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `each()` method and then use `this` to specify the `element` property. This should loop through each image.

```
imageContainer.each(function(index, element) {
    imageContainer.find('li:last').prependTo(imageContainer);
    var state = states[index];
    $(this).animate(state);
});
```

Comment: I have included fiddle example of my problem.